# If we built a mass driver on the moon couldn't we build an O'Neil cylinder for a relatively cheep?

Tags: megastructures

Seems to me that if we built a mass driver on the moon and used solar panels and batteries to run it we could send metals into space for very cheep. Am I missing something?

Comment: This isn't a world building question, but yes. It's really saying "if you do one really difficult thing, then it makes it easier to do an even more difficult thing"/

Comment: Using lunar materials for space construction (and propulsion mass) is a decades-old idea.

Answer (score 0):

Would make it cheaper? Most likely. Earth has an annoyingly deep gravity well. You can only get ~1% of your starting mass up to orbit on a rocket

The lunar mass driver would be quite easy to build with current tech IMHO.

But building a metal smelter that can be powered without coal and in a vacuum sounds a lot harder. I heard somewhere that the moon doesn't have much halides and that could slow you down (needed for smelting aluminum). Smelters have a lot of consumables which you would also need to manufacture on site as well (purified feed stock, crucibles, alloying elements (phosphorus, copper, cobolt, lithium, etc each with a different smelting process of their own! ))

Astroid mining may be a better alternative though. Virtually no lifting involved at all. If you have a non coal, vacuum capable smelter, it is going to work just as well on an astroid as on the moon. Even easer as the lower gravity means it would be easier to move a crucible of molten metal from the smelter over to the fabricator.

That being said it doesn't have to be all or nothing. A hybrid earth, lunar, astroid approach is more than likely going to be needed.